# get solar year in react

Tags: reactjs, date, getdate, jalali-calendar, solar

how can I get current solar year local fa (not full date) in react?

I just need to get solar year (jalali) and I'm using this:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');
```

but it return current date (24/04/1399). I just want (1399)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass additional options, and transform output as you want

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR', {year: 'numeric'} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that.
the answer is :

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString("fa-IR", {year: "numeric" });
```

the above code return 1399. (current jalali year (persian date))

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().getFullYear(); // 2020
```

Comment: I've used that for EN version. I need Solar Year to use in FA version of my project. haw can I get Solar Full Year or convert Gregorian to Solar?

Comment: The Gregorian calendar is a solar calendar. It seems like either the example is incorrect and should be 2020, or you want a different calendar.

Comment: I don't need 2020. I need LocaleDate(fa) that is 1399.
actually my  question was how can I get 1399?